# Battery percentage drops to 0 after restart

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, battery

When I plug off the power cable while the pc is running, it operates till battery is not empty (Normal condition). However, when I reboot the system or shut-down and later back on; battery percentage drops to 0% no matter what battery percentage was before shutdown/reboot.

> lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961/SM963
```

> ❯ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

```
>   native-path:          BAT0   vendor:               SMP   model:     
> L14M3P24   serial:               72   power supply:         yes  
> updated:              Thu 21 Mar 2024 08:08:32 PM +03 (85 seconds ago)
> has history:          yes   has statistics:       yes   battery
>     present:             yes
>     rechargeable:        yes
>     state:               charging
>     warning-level:       none
>     energy:              0.74 Wh
>     energy-empty:        0 Wh
>     energy-full:         24.42 Wh
>     energy-full-design:  45 Wh
>     energy-rate:         25.539 W
>     voltage:             12.386 V
>     charge-cycles:       N/A
>     time to full:        55.6 minutes
>     percentage:          3%
>     capacity:            54.2667%
>     technology:          lithium-polymer
>     icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'   History (charge):
>     1711040912    3.000   charging
>     1711040972    0.000   unknown   History (rate):
>     1711040912    25.539  charging
>     1711040972    0.000   unknown
```

- I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo Legion Y520 Laptop.